# Labeling Layers in Data Driven Pages chops those outside of page?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, data-driven-pages

I am trying to set up a soil layer to be clipped to the extent of my current data driven page.

In Data Frame Properties I have set to clip layers to current data driven page extent.

The flaw with this is that labels for this layer that are outside of the page get chopped off rather than adjusting to the new extent.

i.e. a soil that extends outside of the DDP and is labeled on the outside doesn't show up on my map.

Does anyone know how to change the label properties so that these labels come into the extent of the clip?

Comment: In the past I have converted labels to annotation in a gdb, assigned each label to a page by creating a PageNum attribute and populating, then used the Page Definition in the Definition Query tab to match the current page. I had full control over the placing of labels and angles to match orientation of the page.

Comment: @Clubdebambos I think you should make your comment into an answer

Answer (score 1):

I see no reason why the approach in the comment by @Clubdebambos would not work:

> In the past I have converted labels to annotation in a gdb, assigned
>   each label to a page by creating a PageNum attribute and populating,
>   then used the Page Definition in the Definition Query tab to match the
>   current page. I had full control over the placing of labels and angles
>   to match orientation of the page.

Comment: What if your label needs to be on more than one map? This solution seems like it would be rather tedious for large projects, especially for ones where the data that is being labelled does not contain the page name field (for example, watersheds need to be labelled within a municipality; watersheds can fall inside multiple municipalities).

Comment: @JMVDA you just duplicate the label/annotation once per page it needs to be on with the only difference being the PsgeNumber field value. I actually implemented something like this earlier this year using labels rather than annotation. It was tedious but doable for a modest number.